# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'choices' of undefined

Tags: javascript, undefined

I am trying to improve my JavaScript and I found this: https://jsbin.com/qacolagedo/edit?html,js,output .

But in developer tools, I get this error:

```
qacolagedo.js:54 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'choices' of undefined
    at renderQuestions (qacolagedo.js:54)
    at checkAnswer (qacolagedo.js:72)
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick (runner:1)
```

How can that be fixed?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just stop executing code after calling `finished` function.
For this you can write `return;`

```
else {
    alert("You have a total of " + sumPoints + "/4" + " correct answers!");
    finished();
    return;
}
```

And error occurs because you try to get `choices` from not existing item of `allQuestions` array. Not existing because `zCount` is more than length of `allQuestions` array.

Comment: I did what you told me to do and it worked. Thank you.